# Excluding files from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

I am using `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILES)` to create a spring context based on some xml files.

My `DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILES` look something like this:

```
private static final String[] DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILES = {
            "classpath*:my/package/**/*-beans-start.xml",
            "classpath*:my/package/**/*-beans.xml",
            "classpath*:my/package/**/*-beans-ui.xml"
    };
```

My problem is that I want all the files matching these rules to be used, except one. Is it possible to use some regex to filter files based on their names? Or is there some other way, like through a method or something?

Thanks

Comment: I guess there's a good reason you don't want to rename that one file?

Comment: Yeah, there are other modules using this same pattern, that DO want to include it.